# Rails map link_to to a service object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a big long method that sends an order history to a Customer.  Since this is really a single use method I encapsulated it within a service object to slim up the already massive controller.

My thinking here was: "Ill just place a link in the Customer profile page which automagically fires off that customer's order history for the last 12 months".

Just today when I went to add the link to the Customer profile page, I realized its probably not possible to do this without a controller method to link to.  Do I have this right? or is it possible to map a route to a service object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to declare a route for your action in your `routes.rb` file and define the method in the controller. But the controller's action can just call you service class, like the following:

```
# controller
def history
  @history = YourNamespace::YourClassName.new(@customer, extra_args).compute_history(with, some, args)
end
```

Where `YourNamespace::YourClassName` could be class defined under `<Rails.root>/lib/your_namespace/your_class_name.rb`

And then your controller will still be "slim" and all the logic behind the "history computing" is held by a separated class. Which makes sense because your Controller should not be "responsible" for the compute of the Customer's history.